# VSFTPD - Server refuses to login

Tags: networking, server, ftp, vsftpd

I have installed vsftpd: version 3.0.3 and below is my configuration (vsftpd.conf):

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=NO
anon_root=/srv/ftp/
no_anon_password=YES
listen_address=0.0.0.0
```

When I try to check the connection from a client using the command :

```
wget -O /dev/null  ftp://192.168.3.10
```

I get below message:

```
--2018-03-09 13:52:16--  ftp://192.168.3.10/                                    
  (try: 6) => '.listing'                                                        
Connecting to 192.168.3.10:21... connected.                                     
Logging in as anonymous ...                                                     
The server refuses login.                                                       
Retrying.
```

In  vsftpd.log, I can see below message:

```
Mon Apr 18 17:44:54 2022 [pid 8864] CONNECT: Client "192.168.3.2"
Mon Apr 18 17:44:54 2022 [pid 8863] [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "192.168.3.2", anon password "<no_password>"
Mon Apr 18 17:44:58 2022 [pid 8868] CONNECT: Client "192.168.3.2"
Mon Apr 18 17:44:58 2022 [pid 8867] [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "192.168.3.2", anon password "<no_password>"
Mon Apr 18 17:45:03 2022 [pid 8871] CONNECT: Client "192.168.3.2"
Mon Apr 18 17:45:03 2022 [pid 8870] [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "192.168.3.2", anon password "<no_password>"
```

Kindly let me know how I can resolve this issue

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Read `man vsftpd vsftpd.conf`, especially about the `log_ftp_protocol`  directive.

Comment: @David: I am using Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Comment: @Waltinator. Let me enable add log_ftp_protocol=YES to vsftpd.conf file and check. Thanks

Comment: @Waltinator, Below is the log message  after log_ftp_protocol=YES:
Thu Apr 21 11:08:59 2022 [pid 4331] CONNECT: Client "192.168.3.2"
Thu Apr 21 11:08:59 2022 [pid 4331] FTP response: Client "192.168.3.2", "220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)"
Thu Apr 21 11:08:59 2022 [pid 4331] FTP command: Client "192.168.3.2", "USER anonymous"
Thu Apr 21 11:08:59 2022 [pid 4330] [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "192.168.3.2", anon password "<no_password>"

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.